# Storing several different bits of data into a linked list

Tags: java

I am needing to store 3 different bits of data into a linked list. the first is a name, which i have working, then i need to store the employee number and their occupation. I can't find anything about linking a node to a set of data. any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code that runs, TeamMemberTest:

```
package teammember;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TeamMemberTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Linked List Declaration */
    LinkedList<String> linkedlist = new LinkedList<String>();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean mainloop = true;
    String name;
    int employeeNo;
    String position;
    int choice;
    while(true){
        System.out.println("Menu");
        System.out.print("1. add project \n");
        System.out.print("2. display project \n");
        System.out.print("3. remove project \n");
        System.out.print("4. display all projects \n");
        System.out.print("\nEnter your option: ");

        choice = input.nextInt();

        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                /*add(String Element) is used for adding 
                * the elements to the linked list*/
                name = Input.getString("name: ");
                employeeNo = Input.getInteger("Enter employee number: ");
                position = Input.getString("Enter employee position: ");
                linkedlist.add(name);
                System.out.println("LinkedList after deletion of first and last element: " +linkedlist);
                break;
            case 2:
                name = Input.getString("name: ");
                if(linkedlist.contains(name)){
                    System.out.println("LinkedList does contain " + name);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                name = Input.getString("name: ");
                linkedlist.remove(name);
                System.out.println("LinkedList after deletion of first and last element: " +linkedlist);
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Linked List Content: " +linkedlist);
                break;
            default :
                System.out.println("This is not a valid option try again.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this code below is TeamMember.java:

```
package teammember;

public class TeamMember {
    //variables
    private String name;
    private int employeeNo;
    private String position;

    //the default constant
    public TeamMember(){
        name = " ";
        employeeNo = 0;
        position = " ";
    }
    //overload the constructor
    public TeamMember(String name, int employeeNo, String position){
        this.name = name;
        this.employeeNo = employeeNo;
        this.position = position;
    }
    //the methods
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setemployeeNo(int employeeNo){
        this.employeeNo = employeeNo;
    }
    public void setPosition(String position){
        this.position = position;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public int getemployeeNo(){
        return employeeNo;
    }
    public String getPosition(){
        return position;
    }
}
```

and this is the input code:

```
package teammember;

import java.io.*;
public class Input{
    private static BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    public static Character getCharacter(String prompt){
        Character value;
        System.out.print(prompt);
        try{
            value=Input.input.readLine().charAt(0);
        }
        catch(Exception error){
            // error condition
            value=null;
        }
        return value;
    }

public static Double getDouble(String prompt){
    Double value;
    System.out.print(prompt);
    try{
        value=Double.parseDouble(Input.input.readLine());
    }
    catch(Exception error){
        // error condition
        throw new NumberFormatException();
    }
    return value;
}

public static Integer getInteger(String prompt){
    Integer value;
    System.out.print(prompt);
    try{
        value=Integer.parseInt(Input.input.readLine());
    }
    catch(Exception error){
        // error condition
        throw new NumberFormatException();
    }
    return value;
}

public static String getString(String prompt){
    String string;
    System.out.print(prompt);
    try{
        string=Input.input.readLine();
    }
    catch(Exception error){
        // error condition
        string=null;
    }
    return string;
}
```

}

Comment: `I can't find anything about linking a node to a set of data.` that seems to be your question, but I don't get you. Try to post a short code example and rephrase your question.

Comment: @PeterMmm sorry Im not sure what you mean. What i have posted is what I have. I need to be able to store all 3 data types( name employeeNo position) and be able to pull them back out if i search for a specific name

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a `LinkedList` of `String`, you need to create a `LinkedList` of `TeamMember` as follows:

```
LinkedList<TeamMember> linkedlist = new LinkedList<TeamMember>();
```

Then you need to change the cases accordingly e.g.

```
choice = input.nextInt();
boolean found;
switch (choice) {
case 1:
    name = Input.getString("name: ");
    employeeNo = Input.getInteger("Enter employee number: ");
    position = Input.getString("Enter employee position: ");
    linkedlist.add(new TeamMember(name, employeeNo, position));
    break;

case 2:
    found = false;
    name = Input.getString("name: ");
    for (TeamMember teamMember : linkedlist) {
        if (teamMember.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            System.out.println("Name: " + teamMember.getName() + "Employee No.: "
                    + teamMember.getemployeeNo() + "Position: " + teamMember.getPosition());
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        System.out.println("The team member was not found.");
    }
    break;

case 3:
    found = false;
    name = Input.getString("name: ");
    for (TeamMember teamMember : linkedlist) {
        if (teamMember.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            linkedlist.remove(teamMember);
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        System.out.println("LinkedList after deletion of " + name + "'s record" + ": " + linkedlist);
    } else {
        System.out.println("The team member was not found.");
    }
    break;

case 4:
    System.out.println("Linked List Content: " + linkedlist);
    break;

default:
    System.out.println("This is not a valid option try again.");
    break;
}
```

Make sure to add a `toString()` method in the class, `TeamMember` so that you can simply do like `System.out.println(an-object-of-TeamMember);`. Your IDE can generate the `toString()` method on the click of a button. Given below is an autogenerated `toString()` method for your class by eclipse IDE:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TeamMember [name=" + name + ", employeeNo=" + employeeNo + ", position=" + position + "]";
}
```

Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) to learn more about `toString()`.

Comment: thank you, that took away some errors. How would that be implemented into say case 2 where i would have to display the details from the name inputted?

Comment: thank you so much, this has taken away a massive amount of stress. You must of been working with java for a long time. I am planning on doing some projects from home over the summer to hopefully get some practise in

Comment: @chriscode99 - I've provided you with all the things that you need to progress with your project. Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: would this also work for a binary search tree but instead i would be inputting a project name, start and finish date

Comment: It depends on how you implement your binary search tree.

Comment: the binary search tree would input a name with a start and end date connected to it. so the node would show the name but the if the name is looked for the dates would be shown with it

Comment: @chriscode99 - I suggest you post a new question regarding your binary search tree requirement so that this Q/A can be protected from being polluted. The binary search tree is a different data structure than a `LinkedList`, your new question will be focussed to the binary search tree. Whenever you post that, please make sure you also post whatever you have already done so that it may get more attention.